# How to install grub after fatal error on failed RAID system?

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, hard-drive, raid

I know there are multiple posts about "Executing 'grub-install /dev/dm-3' failed. This is a fatal error", but in my case I have the additional problem of a corrupted RAID system (Windows 7 installation I'm trying to replace with Ubuntu 16.04.3) so I'm not sure how best to proceed.

Here is the RAID failure notice:

```
Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology - Option ROM - 10.1.0.1008
Copyright(C) 2003-10 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
RAID Volumes:
ID Name Level Strip Size Status Bootable
0 Volume0 RAID0(Stripe) 128KB 477.0GB Failed No
Physical Devices Model Serial # Size Type/Status(Vol ID)
0 SAMSUNG [model and serial #] [all sizes 119.2GB 'Member Disk(0)']
1 SAMSUNG 
3 SAMSUNG
```

I may be able to 'enter Configuration Utility' for the above RAID check screen, though this data was shared with me (I've not done this before) ...

What should I do, given the following output of *fdisk -l*? Given the two errors reported (invalid flag, Partition 2 not starting on physical boundary) I don't know what needs to be done.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1532116992
bytes, 2992416 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector
size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size
(minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Invalid flag 0x0000 of EBR (for partition 5) will be corrected by
w(rite). Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680
sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size
(logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x3f64e338

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048     999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         1001470 1000259583 999258114 476.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       357452134  357452150        17   8.5K 3f unknown


Disk /dev/sdb: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 7.5 GiB, 8074035200 bytes, 15769600 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x244117e6

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type /dev/sdd1  *    
2048 15769599 15767552  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/sde: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




Disk /dev/mapper/isw_fedhhbedg_Volume0: 477 GiB, 512133431296 bytes,
1000260608 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size
(logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
131072 bytes / 524288 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier:
0x3f64e338

Device                                  Boot   Start        End  
Sectors   Size Id Type /dev/mapper/isw_fedhhbedg_Volume0-part1        
2048     999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_fedhhbedg_Volume0-part2      1001470 1000259583
999258114 476.5G  5 Extende /dev/mapper/isw_fedhhbedg_Volume0-part5   
1001472 1000259583 999258112 476.5G 8e Linux L

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 468.6 GiB, 503098376192 bytes,
982614016 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size
(logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
131072 bytes / 524288 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 7.9 GiB, 8497659904 bytes,
16596992 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size
(logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
131072 bytes / 524288 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the Internet for something like 'sony vaio bios access' to press F2 or F3 to enter the BIOS, set the RAID configuration to be displayed on startup, pressed Ctrl+I as instructed to edit it, and reset all drives to Non-RAID (apparently losing all data in the process). Then I was able to install Ubuntu 16.04 via the USB flash drive on the first volume -- I elected to erase the disk and use LVM -- after selecting 'Try Ubuntu', connecting to Wifi, and then clicking the 'Install Ubuntu' desktop shortcut (selecting both options to download updates during installation and install third party drivers for Flash, etc).

This enabled me to successfully install Ubuntu 16.04.

I restarted still with the USB drive in. It didn't prompt me to remove it like previous installations. I removed it and then shut down again, resulting in a number of page read failure errors. I did a hard shut off, booted without the USB in, and everything seems fine.